# Nike+ Running App

Tags: gps, gps-tracking

So, I've got Nike+ Running on Android, and I would not like for the whole world to see where I'm running.

Is it possible to still track distance, calories, speed etc without enabling GPS? Is the built-in accelerometer itself enough?

Comment: GPS is a reciever, not a transmitter. Unless you upload your results, you will *not* be broadcasting that to the world. 

I don't believe 'inertial guidence' on phones is that good. In addition, this is off topic here, *unless* you are running with a tablet strapped to your arm.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Nike+ is a social app that automatically shares your runs. So if you have GPS enabled it will share your path letting everyone know where were you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nike+ lets you select privacy options for your sharing.

Public, social, private